# How do I get all Gini indices in my decision tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have made a decision tree using sklearn, here, under the SciKit learn DL package, viz. `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x,y)`.

How do I get the gini indices for all possible nodes at each step? `graphviz` only gives me the gini index of the node with the lowest gini index, ie the node used for split.

For example, the image below (from `graphviz`) tells me the gini score of the Pclass_lowVMid right index which is 0.408, but not the gini index of the Pclass_lower or Sex_male at that step. I just know the Gini index of Pclass_lower and Sex_male must be greater than (0.408*0.7 + 0) but that's it.

[image: decision tree]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`export_graphviz`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz) shows impurity for all nodes, at least in version `0.20.1`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from graphviz import Source

data = load_iris()
X, y = data.data, data.target

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X, y)

graph = Source(export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, feature_names=data.feature_names))
graph.format = 'png'
graph.render('dt', view=True);
```

[image]

The impurity values for all nodes are also accessible in the `impurity` attribute of the `tree`.

```
clf.tree_.impurity
array([0.66666667, 0.        , 0.5       , 0.16803841, 0.04253308])
```

Answer (score 1):

Gini index of pclass node = gini index of left node * (no. of samples in left node/ no. samples at left node + no. of samples at right node) + gini index of right node * ( no. of samples in left node/ no. samples at left node + no. of samples at right node) 
So here it will be

```
Gini index of pclass = 0 + .408 *(7/10) = 0.2856
```

Comment: perhaps, 0.408(?)

Comment: sorry i was on mobile so there is lot of typo.

Comment: ur correct. by bad its .408 not .48. i have corrected it. hope u i understood u correctly.

Comment: Oh, I made a typo when typing my question too haha. Actually, I know that formula and know how to get the indices manually. I'm hoping scikitlearn can do it for me haha.